# Sharepoint 2013 Navigation

Tags: navigation, managed-navigation

It is possible to change the name of my Sub site Navigation? At the moment I have two links, One is called Issue Log which takes me to my homepage and the another also called Issue Log which takes me to a custom list.  I would like to rename the Homepage Link to be Issue Management

Comment: Click the gear icon which is present in your SharePoint site > Then click on site settings > Once you are in site settings page, click on the navigation present under Look and feel. Once you are in the navigation page, under "Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting" go to current navigation and select the link which you would like rename and click on edit then change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the navigation items from the site settings page:

> {yoursite}/_layouts/15/settings.aspx

You can access this section from the Settings cog too:

[image]

On the site settings page you should have a **Look and Feel** section. Check for a **Navigation** option in this section:
[image]

If you don't see this option, you may first need to enable the site **publishing feature**. To do so, click on site features:
[image]

Scroll down and locate the publishing feature, and then enable it:
[image]

Go back to **site settings** and click on **Navigation**. On the navigation page you will see the section that corresponds to your left hand side navigation on the site:
[image]

Use the controls to add, remove and edit links. You may need to create a new link called "Issue Management" and have it point to your list.